# Comparison between 'int' and 'char'?

Tags: c

The result of the below code is "No" but I am not sure 'Why' ? Searched in google and found some information but I am confused... Can someone explain me ? Thanks !

```
int i = 23;
char c = -23;

if (i < c)
{
    printf("Yes");
}
else
{
    printf("No");
}
```

Comment: `23 < -23` is false, why are you surprised?

Comment: I think he might have meant to be asking why he can do such a comparison between a char and an int to begin with - but not sure @HolyBlackCat

Comment: `char` is an integer type in C.

Comment: ... which is promoted to a 'full' `int` before the comparison.

Comment: Yes, I am a little bit confused, because it is comparison between char and int. Char is promoted to int ?

Comment: Every char in C has an corresponding integer. Look up ASCII table to learn more.

Comment: A `char` is just a small integer type, similar to `short`.  It is usually signed, but I believe it may be unsigned in some implementations.

Comment: `char` is promoted to `int`, indeed. But this does not change its value (the situation changes when one of them is `unsigned`). It is still `-23` but now, as `int` it is represented on more bytes (`char` is represented on one byte). And the comparison `23 < -23` still produces the same result, no matter on how many bytes are the values represented in memory.

Comment: The type `char` is an integer type, meaning that it actually stores numbers not characters. So when you do an assignment such as `char c = 'a';` what is actually stored in the variable `c` is the number respective to the character `a` according to a characters table (look into the ASCII table to find the exact number). The type `char` is the smallest integer, typically occupying only 8 bits, which means that it can only represent a maximum of 256 distinct integer numbers (from 0 to 255 without signal, or from -128 to 127 with signal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately (imho) `char` is considered an integer type and you can treat it as an integer type without any explicit cast.

`char` is a different type than `signed char` and `unsigned char`. Whether `char` is unsigned or signed is implementation defined.

When used in arithmetic operations (including comparisons) integer types with rank less or equal to rank of `int` undergo [integer promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) so your code is equivalent with:

```
if ((int)i < (int)c)
```

Another use for `char` is to access raw memory. `C` doesn't have a byte type and `char` is ... the byte type.

---

Just because you can doesn't mean you should. Use `char` for ... well ... characters. For memory access a lot of API uses `char*`, but if you can you should use `unsigned char*`. For small integers if you really need to save the space use `int8_t` and `uint8_t` which should be aliases for `signed char` and `unsigned char` respectively.

Comment: And that is why you should ONLY use char literals with the type char and numbers with signed/unsigned char.